# Unable to use gdb with hdf5 c++ application

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, conda, hdf5

I am trying to use gdb to debug an hdf5 C++ application that I have written. The h5 package that I am using was installed using conda. The command that I am using is:

```
h5c++ hdf5.cpp
```

This generates an executable which I then run with gdb as follows:

```
gdb a.out
```

gdb launches alright. But when I add breakpoint using:

```
b 10
```

or any line number, it gives a message: *No line 10 in file "init.c"*
When I press run, it runs the whole program at once (which I don't want) and exits. The h5c++ -show command gives the following output:

```
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ -I/i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++17 -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -L/i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/lib /i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/lib/libhdf5_hl_cpp.a /i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/lib/libhdf5_cpp.a /i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/lib/libhdf5_hl.a /i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/lib/libhdf5.a -L/i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/lib -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-rpath,/i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/lib -L/i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/lib -g -lrt -lpthread -lz -ldl -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/tensorflow/anaconda2/lib
```

I think this has to do with the compiler the compiler that it is using. I tried replacing x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ with my native g++ compiler in the h5c++ script but that gives linker error.
Please suggest how should make my h5 application work with gdb. Should I install hdf5 from source since I don't have sudo access? I am working on a Linux machine.

Comment: Does `b hdf5.cpp:10` work?

Comment: In order to use hdf5 with your native c++ compiler, simply link the hdf5 libraries using `-lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5` (but you may also need an appropriate `-L` flag, if it cannot find the libraries)

Comment: I tried the command: `g++ -lhdf5_cpp -L/i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/hdf5/hdf5_pre-built/hdf5-1.8.20-linux-centos7-x86_64-gcc485-shared/lib -I/i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/hdf5/hdf5_pre-built/hdf5-1.8.20-linux-centos7-x86_64-gcc485-shared/include hdf5.cpp` It creates a warning: `/usr/bin/ld: warning: libhdf5.so.10, needed by /i3c/hpcl/sms821/software/hdf5/hdf5_pre-built/hdf5-1.8.20-linux-centos7-x86_64-gcc485-shared/lib/libhdf5_cpp.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)` and many linker errors.

Comment: @aschepler, no. That does not work either.

Comment: You have to enable debugging symbols. You can do this by adding extra flags to `h5c++`. For example, I would add `-g -O0`, since you are using the GNU compiler. i.e. `h5c++ -g -O0 hdf5.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

I simply installed hdf5 from the source files. While configuring the installation I turned the `--enable-build-mode` and `--enable-symbol` switches. Hdf5 has a dependency on szip which I also installed from source code. My exact configuration was as follows:

```
    ./configure --prefix=<hdf5 install directory> --enable-cxx --enable-build-mode=debug --enable-symbols=yes --enable-profiling=yes --with-szlib=<szip install directory>
```

The above solution worked and I was able to compile my h5 application using `h5c++ hdf5.cpp` and also use gdb to debug it.